# Creating a long sequence from a single row using the apply function family instead of a loop

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to create a number sequence from a single row when I know the maximum number.

I've actually done this successfully using a loop but want to know how to do this using the `apply` family of functions and so reduce the number of steps and intermediate objects created.

I've tried combinations of `apply`, `lapply` and `mapply` to no avail.

Here's the data:

```
df <- structure(list(location = c("doncaster", "dover", "dundee", "eastbourne"), num.pages = c(6, 3, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here's the loop:

```
for(i in seq_along(df$location)) {
  assign(
    paste0("loc_seq_", df$location[[i]]),
    seq(from = 1, to = df$num.pages[[i]]) %>%
      enframe(name    = NULL, value = 'page.seq') %>%
      mutate(location = df$location[[i]])
  )
}
```

I then use:

```
location_sequence <- bind_rows(mget(ls(pattern = "loc_seq_*")))
```

... to produce the correct result.

How can I use the `apply` family to get the same result from my `df` starting point above please?

Comment: Try `tidyr::uncount(df, num.pages)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 uncount(num.pages) %>%
 group_by(location) %>%
 mutate(page.seq = 1:n())

  location   page.seq
   <chr>         <int>
 1 doncaster         1
 2 doncaster         2
 3 doncaster         3
 4 doncaster         4
 5 doncaster         5
 6 doncaster         6
 7 dover             1
 8 dover             2
 9 dover             3
10 dundee            1
11 dundee            2
12 dundee            3
13 eastbourne        1
14 eastbourne        2
15 eastbourne        3
16 eastbourne        4
```

Comment: Didn't know about uncount. thanks